# plot command isn't recognizing column names

Tags: r

Recently when I tried to plot in R I keep getting this error. Can anyone tell me why I can't seem to do a scatter plot? I've pasted the terminal screen below.

```
tcmg2o4 <-read.table("~/Documents/research/metal.oxides/TcMg2O4.inverse/energydata.txt")

tcmg2o4
                 V1            V2
1  Lattice_constant  Total_energy
2               8.0 -371.63306746
3               8.1   -375.035492
4               8.2  -378.8669067
5               8.3 -380.34136459
6               8.4  -382.3921237
7               8.5 -383.60394736
8               8.6 -384.09517631
9               8.7 -383.77668067
10              8.8 -382.43806866
11              8.9 -381.42213458
12              9.0 -379.63327976

attach(tcmg2o4)
plot(Lattice_constant, Total_energy)

Error in plot(Lattice_constant, Total_energy) : 
object 'Lattice_constant' not found

plot(V1,V2)
```

Comment: It might have worked with: plot(as.numeric(as.character(V1)), as.numeric(as.character(V2) ) ). As itwas you got two factor variables because of what 'mnel' showed you. I think the NA's that came from the headers would just get ignored. There an R-FAQ itemregarding how to convert factors to numeric properly.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are not reading the column names as column names. to do this use
`header = T`

```
 tcmg2o4 <-read.table("~/Documents/research/metal.oxides/TcMg2O4.inverse/energydata.txt", header = T)
```

In your case, the `read.table` call has created column names `V1` and `V2` and these columns will both be factor variables.

You can check the structure of your read in object by

```
str(tcmg2o4)
## 'data.frame':    11 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ Lattice_constant: num  8 8.1 8.2 8.3 8.4 8.5 8.6 8.7 8.8 8.9 ...
##  $ Total_energy    : num  -372 -375 -379 -380 -382 ...
```

I would also avoid using `attach`

instead use `with` or

```
with(tcmg2o4, plot(Lattice_constant, Total_energy))
```

or the fact that it is a 2 column data.frame

```
plot(tcmg2o4)
```

or use a `formula` to specify your x and y axis (`y~x`)

```
plot(Total_energy ~ Lattice_constant, data = tcmg2o4)
```

which will all give the same result and be much clearer as to where the data is stored

[image]